# How do I retrieve the input parameters for the current object

Tags: python, factory-boy

How do I get the raw value which was passed to MyClass by Factory Boy?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.processed = f'***{raw}***'

class MyClassFactory(factory.Factory):

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass

    raw = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(['a', 'b'])

o = MyClassFactory.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

The raw value passed to your `__init__` function by the factory during object instantiation can simply be accessed through the `raw` attribute of the object `o`:

```py
raw_value = o.raw
```

Just a side note, please be aware that `fuzzy` module has been deprecated a few years ago (cf. the [official documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fuzzy.html)), you may want to use this line of code instead:

```py
    raw = factory.Faker("random_element", elements=(['a', 'b'])
```

In the future however, it's still not clear if the `fuzzy` will be completely removed from Faker or not (see [this Github thread](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/271#issuecomment-1231765227)).

Comment: `.raw` does not exist on the object. It has been transformed. However I need it to assert a test

Comment: Then the easiest solution might be to `import random` in your `test` module, to call `raw_value = random.choice(["a", "b"])` and `MyClassFactory.create(raw=raw_value)`. In other therms, you can explicitly generate a random raw value outside of the factory and provide it to the factory.

Comment: doesn't the class randomise it also? thereby changing the value?

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear: my suggestion was to bypass the generation of `raw` in your `MyClassFactory` by providing a value to `raw` in your test itself. "The purpose of factory_boy is to provide a default way of getting a new instance, *while still being able to override some fields on a per-call basis*."

Comment: Otherwise, you could for instance edit your `__init__` method to keep track of the original `raw` value in a private attribute, which could be called `__raw` and which could be accessed by a custom getter `get_raw`. Or a similar thing could be done using Factory Boy's `post_generation` (see [here](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.post_generation)) method. But my initial suggestion above was probably the easiest solution.